# How can i upload photos, using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Is there a way I can upload a photo using jquery, where once uploaded, the thumbnail will show on the left instantly.

I really love this sort of user experience, are there any plugins or tutorials I could use to help achieve this?

Comment: P.s im also using php for the backend, so the request will go to a php file through ajax!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/ajax-multiple-file-upload-form-using-jquery/